# KnockoutJS foreach loop from 2-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, foreach, mapping, knockout.js

I have an JSON string that gets returned from the server that i'm trying to bind to a foreach loop using KnockoutJS

the JSON returned looks like the following:

```
    [{"FileID":19,
"ParentID":6,
"SubType":"Page",
"FileName":"nav_secondary_bg.png",
"FileExtension":null,"Filetype":"20",
"FileMethod":null,"FileGroupName":null,
"FileLocation":"/uploads/Page/resized/nav_secondary_bg.png_thumb",
"FilenameOriginal":"nav_secondary_bg.png",
"AltTag":null,
"DateUploaded":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/",
"OrigFilesize":0,
"OrigFile":null,
"SiteID":0,
"Display":"y",
"FileDefault":false},
{... Next Item...}]
```

and my html code:

```
<div id="itemImages" >
     <ul data-bind="foreach: Image">       
        <li>        
        <span data-bind="value: FileName"></span>
        </li>        
        </ul>
    </div>     
</div>
```

i have tried following the example on the tutorials (http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) however it cant get the mapping plugin to correctly map the data and get the forloop working at all.

Update:

using johns example, im now binding the data to the UI however struggling to update the bindings after new data has be recieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle you can compare with yours:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/y4b9e/

Make sure you use the [text](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) binding for your span, not the value binding.  The [value](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) binding is used to bind properties to form elements (input, select, ...), whereas the text binding will set the innerText or textContext of the associated DOM element (p, span, ...)

Comment: thats perfect! found out i had almost the same code however multiple bindings on the page were causing problems.

Comment: Ok so this works fine, however i cant seem to update the bindings after its been created, again i get the JSON string from the server but the binding never updates the UI

Comment: You could also write the update line like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/y4b9e/5/

Comment: finally revisiting this, that all works great, but how would i update the bindings in code instead of on a button click? i have an piece of js code that sends data back to the server, once complete update the binding?

Comment: I just use the button just as the trigger to callback a method. You can use what ever you want as your trigger.  Here is an update that sets a 3 second timer callback: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/y4b9e/13/